# How to remove the existing text inside <p> tag if the text is greater than 100 or specific length using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

is there any way to delete or replace text with (...) if the text is inside the .class p tag is greater than 100 characters?

Example I have this long text inside on the p tag:

```
<div class='classname'>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis nibh velit, suscipit bibendum sagittis non, consequat vestibulum ante. Praesent in fermentum turpis. Nam nec erat vulputate, imperdiet mi ac, porttitor diam. Quisque posuere odio vel nulla varius dictum. Vestibulum malesuada tellus id cursus pretium. Cras volutpat, diam vel molestie bibendum, neque risus ullamcorper augue, vel convallis odio purus hendrerit quam. Mauris convallis dolor vel ex placerat, non imperdiet dolor lacinia. </p>
```

Expected Result:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis nibh velit, suscipit bibendum sagittis non, consequat ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let peles = document.querySelectorAll('.classname > p')
for(p of peles){
  let txt = p.innerText
  txt = txt.replace(txt.substring(100),'...')
  p.innerText = txt
}
```

```html
<div class='classname'>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis nibh velit, suscipit bibendum sagittis non, consequat vestibulum ante. Praesent in fermentum turpis. Nam nec erat vulputate, imperdiet mi ac, porttitor diam. Quisque posuere odio vel nulla varius dictum. Vestibulum malesuada tellus id cursus pretium. Cras volutpat, diam vel molestie bibendum, neque risus ullamcorper augue, vel convallis odio purus hendrerit quam. Mauris convallis dolor vel ex placerat, non imperdiet dolor lacinia. </p>
<div>
```

Comment: Thanks @lucumt, is there also any way to remove existing p tags? if it is more than 1 inside the class name?

Comment: @cdt You can extract the text to a variable,then create new element for the `div`

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Gets all p elements inside element with class: classname
const paras = document.querySelectorAll(".classname > p");
paras.forEach( p => {
    const text = p.textContent;
    if (text.length > 100){
        const newText = text.slice(0, 100) + " ...";
    p.textContent = newText;
}
})
```

```html
<div class='classname'>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis nibh velit, suscipit bibendum sagittis non, consequat vestibulum ante. Praesent in fermentum turpis. Nam nec erat vulputate, imperdiet mi ac, porttitor diam. Quisque posuere odio vel nulla varius dictum. Vestibulum malesuada tellus id cursus pretium. Cras volutpat, diam vel molestie bibendum, neque risus ullamcorper augue, vel convallis odio purus hendrerit quam. Mauris convallis dolor vel ex placerat, non imperdiet dolor lacinia. </p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis nibh velit, suscipit bibendum sagittis non, consequat vestibulum ante. Praesent in fermentum turpis. Nam nec erat vulputate, imperdiet mi ac, porttitor diam. Quisque posuere odio vel nulla varius dictum. Vestibulum malesuada tellus id cursus pretium. Cras volutpat, diam vel molestie bibendum, neque risus ullamcorper augue, vel convallis odio purus hendrerit quam. Mauris convallis dolor vel ex placerat, non imperdiet dolor lacinia. </p>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** Answering question in the comments

```js
const parasExceptFirst = document.querySelectorAll(".classname p:not(:first-child)");

parasExceptFirst.forEach( p => {
  p.remove()
})
```

```html
<div class='classname'>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis nibh velit, suscipit bibendum sagittis non, consequat vestibulum ante. Praesent in fermentum turpis. Nam nec erat vulputate, imperdiet mi ac, porttitor diam. Quisque posuere odio vel nulla varius dictum. Vestibulum malesuada tellus id cursus pretium. Cras volutpat, diam vel molestie bibendum, neque risus ullamcorper augue, vel convallis odio purus hendrerit quam. Mauris convallis dolor vel ex placerat, non imperdiet dolor lacinia. </p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis nibh velit, suscipit bibendum sagittis non, consequat vestibulum ante. Praesent in fermentum turpis. Nam nec erat vulputate, imperdiet mi ac, porttitor diam. Quisque posuere odio vel nulla varius dictum. Vestibulum malesuada tellus id cursus pretium. Cras volutpat, diam vel molestie bibendum, neque risus ullamcorper augue, vel convallis odio purus hendrerit quam. Mauris convallis dolor vel ex placerat, non imperdiet dolor lacinia. </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ammar, is there also any way to remove existing p tags?  if it is more than 1 inside the class name?

Comment: Edited to answer your question @cdt :). Feel free to select my answer as accepted if you think I answered your question adequately.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Configure/customize these variables.
    var showChar = 100;  // How many characters are shown by default
    var ellipsestext = "...";
    

    $('.more').each(function() {
        var content = $(this).html();
 
        if(content.length > showChar) {
 
            var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
            var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);
 
            var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext+ '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';
 
            $(this).html(html);
        }
 
    });
 
    $(".morelink").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
            $(this).removeClass("less");
            $(this).html(moretext);
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("less");
            $(this).html(lesstext);
        }
        $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
        $(this).prev().toggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: This uses jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try css， like this:

```
display: -webkit-box;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-line-clamp: 2;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
line-height: 1.5;
```

It feels a little better to use this way.